# Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\Amit'

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I want to connect my sql server database with java. here is the code I have

```
package myPackage;
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=sample1;";
    String uname="DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\\Amit";
    String pass="";
    
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
    System.out.println("command completed sucessfully");        
    
    Statement stmt =(Statement) conn.createStatement();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM tblPerson";
    ResultSet rs =((java.sql.Statement) stmt).executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) +" "+rs.getString(2) +" "+rs.getString(3) );
    }
    

}

}
```

**Please note that**

- I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 18.
- I have added the mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jar in the build path.

**my SQL server details**

- server type: Database Engine
- server name: DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\SQLEXPRESS
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
- User name: DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\Amit
- Password:

**I am getting the following error-**

Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\Amit'. ClientConnectionId:497452a3-a4f3-40a8-b68e-864e269ad66a
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5233)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3988)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:85)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3932)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2713)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at myPackage.Test1.main(Test1.java:22)

Comment: It looks like you want to do Windows authentication. If so, you need to specify `integratedSecurity=true` in the connection string, and make sure that the driver is setup correctly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You actually can use Windows Auth (NTLM) by providing a user name and password in Java.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. here is the correct code for...

```
package myPackage;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=sample1;integratedSecurity=true";
    String uname="DESKTOP-6U7R1AC\\Amit";
    String pass="";
    
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
    System.out.println("command completed sucessfully");        
    
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM tblPerson";
    ResultSet rs =((java.sql.Statement) stmt).executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) +" "+rs.getString(2) +" "+rs.getString(3) );
    }
    

}

}
```

**The changes I did.**

fist set the `integratedSecurity=true` and then I was getting an error saying that `sqljdbc_auth.dll` is not found in `java.library.path` . Then I added the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in `java.library.path` and it worked.